# Resize list of images with scipy imresize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I got a list of images that I want to resize to a certain size.

I want to use the imresize function of scipy for this and got the following code that is not working as expected:

```
imgs = get_imgs()
for img in imgs:
    img = imresize(img, (82, 100))
```

If I print out the shape of the imgs array, it is still the original size (178, 218). Could somebody explain why this is not working?

Unfortunately I didn't find any other questions of resizing a list of images with this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` variable is only valid in the `for` loop.
so the result of the `imresize` function is lost after the loop.

you have to build a new list with the results.

```
imgs = get_imgs()
res = []
for img in imgs:
    res.append(imresize(img, (82, 100)))
```

the pytonic way to do is is to use map :

```
res = map(lambda img : imresize(img, (82, 100), get_imgs())
```

Comment: you meant res = [] right? Otherwise I would get an error for the append command.

But thanks for the explanation! I thought it would be a usual case to just have the images replaced in the list with the resized images. Or atleast having a parameter that says inplace=True/False like in pandas.

Comment: @TheDude yes, [].
in the loop, img is just a pointer to the current element.
it is not the pointer in the list.
imgs[i] would be a pointer in the list, but it is not how the for statement works.